# Как повернуть обьект к мыши?

Tags: python, turtle

Всем привет! Я не понимаю как сделать так чтобы предмет или объект повернулся к указателю мыши. Я попробовал найти позицию мыши и повернуть объект но не вышло. Но Этот метод я попробовал месяц назад. Поэтому код этого метода у меня нету. Вот код:

```py
import turtle as tr

def keypress():
    pule.speed(0)
    pule.goto(0,0)
    pule.st()
    pule.speed(2)
    pule.fd(500)
    pule.ht()

wn = tr.Screen()
wn.setup(width = 1.0, height = 1.0)
canvas = wn.getcanvas()
root = canvas.winfo_toplevel()
root.overrideredirect(1)

wn.bgcolor("green")
player = tr.Turtle()
player.pu()
player.shape("circle")
player.color("lightgreen")

war = tr.Turtle()
war.pu()
war.shape("circle")
war.color("red")
war.goto(50,50)

pule = tr.Turtle()
pule.pu()

wn.onkeypress(keypress,"space")
wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

P.S. Заглянул в этот ваш turtle и вижу **turtle.towards** - так чего ж ещё надо...

---

Имея координаты мыши и объекта, можно рассчитать требуемый угол - направление (не забудьте о радианах и градусах)

```
dir_angle = atan2(my-oy, mx-ox)
```

Подозреваю, что в черепашьей графике может потребоваться угол поворота от текущего направления `fi` - или через разность с вышеуказанным (при этом следить, чтобы не более 180 градусов крутиться), или

```
rot_angle = atan2((my-oy)*cos(fi)- (mx-ox)*sin(fi), (my-oy)*sin(fi)+(mx-ox)*cos(fi))
```

Comment: atan2 это что? Написал turtle.atan2 , wn.atan2 но не сработало.

Comment: Кстати,  во моем тетраде(то есть там все команды turtle) не было такой команды

Comment: atan2 это скорее всего из математики, в math посмотрите.